# Speeding up Position for finding the indices of a small number of integer elements in a large matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I have a large $100 \times 4000$ element matrix composed of integer elements, `testMatrix`, and I was to use `Position` to find the indices of integers larger than some threshold value `thresholdValue`.  The following works:

```
Position[testMatrix, x_ /; x >= thresholdValue, 2]
```

However it takes over $\approx 150$ milliseconds to execute.

Given that the number of positions is typically around $10^3$, is there a way to achieve a significant speedup for this procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
testMatrix = RandomInteger[10^4, {100, 4000}];
Position[testMatrix, x_ /; x >= 1000] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
Position[UnitStep[testMatrix - 1000], 1] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
Compile[{}, Position[UnitStep[testMatrix - 1000], 1]][] //  Hash // AbsoluteTiming
SparseArray[UnitStep[testMatrix - 1000]]["NonzeroPositions"] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{0.665038, 953655867}
{0.282016, 953655867}
{0.038002, 953655867}
{0.032002, 953655867}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

With compile little more speed up!

```
f = Compile[{{mat, _Integer, 2}, {th, _Real}}, 
     Position[(Map[Boole[# > th] &, mat, {2}]), 1], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Test

```
SeedRandom[1];
mat = RandomInteger[10^4, {100, 4000}];
f[mat, 1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
Position[mat, x_ /; x >= 1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
Position[UnitStep[mat - 1000], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
SparseArray[UnitStep[mat - 1000]]["NonzeroPositions"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.015014, Null}
>
> {0.398360, Null}
>
> {0.293312, Null}
>
> {0.032029, Null}